# Using straight edge with a cost and no direction

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to figure out how to draw an edge without a direction, as well as put a cost on it in Zodiac, but with no luck:

Library: ZodiacGraph

My current attempt is:

```
zodiac::NodeHandle v1 = handle.createNode("v1");
zodiac::NodeHandle v2 = handle.createNode("v2");

zodiac::EdgeGroupPair* group = new zodiac::EdgeGroupPair(scene, v1.data(), v2.data());
zodiac::StraightEdge* edge = new zodiac::StraightEdge(scene, group, v1.data(), v2.data());
edge->setLabelText("45");
edge->updateLabel();
```

However it still shows the direction, also the cost is not showing.